# How can I keep the user's information updated in my Next.js project? (Using next-auth)

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have a problem with my Next.js project. I have a model User with email, pass, balance, role...
In the header of my aplication I show the balance of the user like this:
[Header of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlBKy.png)

To display the user's information, I am using the `useSession()` function from next-auth. However, my issue is that the information does not remain updated because I have a feature that allows the user to add funds. While the funds are correctly added in the database (MongoDB), they are not being reflected in the frontend.

The user needs to sign out and then sign in again to see the updated information.

I thought of using `getServerSession()` or Server-Side Rendering to correctly display and update the user's information in the header. However, I don't know how to accomplish this. I tried, but I failed.

Could you help me and explain how I can do this? Thank you in advance.

Keep the user information updated in the header of my project